# Newly cloned Mac Hard Drive not showing new name

Tags: macos, hard-drive

So I just cloned my Mac hard drive to running Lion 10.7.4 to a new larger drive (both are internal drives on a Mac Pro). Everything went fine, but I cannot tell the drives apart as they now have the same name.

If I click on the drives and look in their info panel, the drives are named Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD 1. But these names do not appear on the desktop nor do they appear in the Startup Disk Utility making it very hard for me to know which drive I am booting from.

Where can I name them so I can tell them apart?

Comment: Well I did some more research and found the answer, here it is if anyone needs it. Click the hard disk icon on your desktop and press Return.
If you don’t see the hard disk icon, choose Finder > Preferences, click General, and then select “Hard disks.”

Type a name.
You can use numbers and most symbols. You cannot include a colon (:) or start the name with a period (.).

Press Return.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Self-answer by the OP:</sub>

> Well I did some more research and found the answer, here it is if anyone needs it.
>
> Click the hard disk icon on your desktop and press Return. If you don’t see the hard disk icon, choose Finder > Preferences, click General, and then select “Hard disks.” Type a name.
>
> You can use numbers and most symbols. You cannot include a colon (:) or start the name with a period (.). Press Return.